# Find the minimum value of $\sqrt {2x^2+2y^2} +\sqrt {y^2+x^2-4y+4} +\sqrt {x^2+y^2-4x-4y+8}$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

Given that $0\lt x\lt 2$ and $0\lt y\lt 2$ then find the minimum value of $$\sqrt {2x^2+2y^2} +\sqrt {y^2+x^2-4y+4} +\sqrt {x^2+y^2-4x-4y+8}$$

My try:

On factorisation we need minimum value of $$\sqrt {2x^2+2y^2} +\sqrt {(y-2)^2+x^2} +\sqrt {(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2}$$

On seeing it for first time,  the only thing that popped up was using the Minkowski inequality but I am not getting proper sequences for its application. I tried as much as I could to use this inequality but failed.

I tried substituting $x=2\cos \alpha$ and $y=2\cos \beta$ (where $\alpha, \beta \in \left(0,\frac {\pi}{2}\right)$ )on seeing the constraints on $x$ and $y$ but continuing it was very cumbersome so dropped the method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S : It would be very great if someone hints at how I could use the Minkowski inequality efficiently.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Hmm, you seem to hint on some real analysis inequalities. Is this an exercise from such a lesson ?

Comment: @Rebellos Maybe, I don't know because it was given to me by one of my friends. I solved it using a geometrical approach but I wanted to know if there could an algebraic solution to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still use Minkowski as:
$$\sqrt{(x+y)^2+(y-x)^2}+\sqrt{(2-y)^2+x^2}+\sqrt{(2-x)^2+(2-y)^2}\geq\sqrt{(x+y+2-y+2-x)^2+(y-x+x+2-y)^2}=\sqrt{20}.$$
One can check that the equality is attained when: $$(x,y) = \left(\frac 25,\frac 65\right).$$

Comment: This is what I really wanted.  Excellent way to break $x^2+y^2$

Answer (score 2):

You can dress up your geometric argument as an inequality in $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $z=x+iy$, $a=2i$, $b=2-2i$.  Then
\begin{align}
\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2} &= \lvert (1-i)z\rvert\\
\sqrt{y^2+x^2-4y+4} &= \lvert z-a\rvert\\
\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4x-4y+8} &= \lvert -iz-b\rvert
\end{align}
So the triangle inequality gives
$$
\lvert (1-i)z\rvert + \lvert z-a\rvert + \lvert -iz-b\rvert \ge \lvert a-b\rvert
$$
with equality if and only if the four points $a,z,-iz,b$ are all on the same line and in this order.  Now argue why such a $z$ exists.